# Can't find qwt when use cmake of Elmer

Tags: qt, cmake, qwt

I'm trying to install Elmer with GUI, the qt5 and Qwt are required in CMakeLists.txt. I installed Qt5 and Qwt via Homebrew, but seems they can not find them.

The CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
IF(WITH_QWT)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DEG_QWT)
  FIND_PACKAGE(Qwt REQUIRED
              )
  FIND_PATH(QWT_INCLUDE_DIR qwt.h)
#  SET(QWT_INCLUDE_DIR "c:/b/qwt-6.1.0/include")
#  SET(QWT_LIBRARY "c:/b/qwt-6.1.0/lib/qwt.dll")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  [ElmerGUI] Qwt:             " ${Qwt_FOUND})
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  [ElmerGUI] QWT_LIBRARY:     " ${QWT_LIBRARY})
  MESSAGE(STATUS "  [ElmerGUI] QWT_INCLUDE_DIR: " ${QWT_INCLUDE_DIR})
  MESSAGE(STATUS "------------------------------------------------")
ENDIf()
```

And the error message I got is:

```
CMake Error at ElmerGUI/CMakeLists.txt:64 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qwt" with any of
  the following names:

    QwtConfig.cmake
    qwt-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qwt" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qwt_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qwt" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I tried to add **PATHS** to CMakeLists.txt and it won't works.
Could someone tell me where I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I tried to add PATHS to CMakeLists.txt" - What **exactly** have you tried? Have you tried to set variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `c:/b/qwt-6.1.0`? This setting should be performed before `find_package` call because exactly that call emits the error. (But it is better to set given variable in your environment, or set it in CMake GUI when you configure your project).

Comment: Ah...sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using MacOS 12.3.1, not windows, and what I tried is add **PATHS /opt/homebrew/Cellar/qwt-qt5/** after find_package(Qwt REQUIRED at the same line. And I also tried to export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to the qwt directory...